# How can we find the surface density on the surface of the conducting plate nearest to a point charge without using image method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauss-law

The problem I'm having trouble with is this. If a point charge Q is located a distance y from the surface of an infinite conducting plane, what is the surface density on the surface of the conductor nearest to the charge Q? (The question said to not use the image method, which I don't know how to use it anyway.)
So far I have used the gauss law, by drawing a closed surface(basically a cylinder) around the closest surface. Assuming that the electric field is uniform in the infinitely small area I drew, I was able to come up that the density of the surface should be $$ϭ=E\times\epsilon_0$$
I'm currently stuck how to deal with the E. Since the charge of the infinite conducting plane isn't uniformly distributed, the magnitude of the electric field near the closest surface doesn't have any formulas or anything. Is there any way I can deal with the E without the image method?

Comment: You *might* be able to use separation of variables & Laplace's equation, taking as your region of interest the hemisphere of radius $y$ bounded by the conducting sheet and having the point charge at its apex.  But it would be a very non-standard problem.

Comment: Well, this problem is just made for the image charge. So please state, what you do not understand ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges)).